# FXCop / Code Analysis on WCF DataContract Classes with Array - Creates CA1819 Error

Tags: arrays, wcf, code-analysis, datacontract, datamember

I have the following WCF data contract class:

```
[DataContract]
public class BinaryResponse : ResponseBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Nice and simple, works exactly as I need it to.  However I am now running this through the full code analysis ruleset.  This generates the following warning:

```
CA1819 : Microsoft.Performance : Change 'BinaryResponse.Payload' to return a collection or make it a method.
```

Having looked at the [help page for this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(PROPERTIESSHOULDNOTRETURNARRAYS)&rd=true) the solution is a simple one.  However the solution doesn't really fit with WCF datamembers.

So the question is, how can I refactor this class to still be useable as a WCF datacontract and also pass the code analysis?

Cheers

Comment: I would bite the bullet and make this a method, not a property. I would not expose members like this.

Comment: Return a collection, because the method will be transformed on the client side anyway.

Comment: I mean, when you click Add Service Reference and then the button Advanced, you can choose the type for collections, and the array is default type there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do change the byte array to an enumerable or collection, like tehe following:

```
[DataContract]
public class BinaryResponse : ResponseBase
{
    [DataMember] public ICollection<byte> Payload { get; set; }
}
```

or you can keep the byte[] attribute in a private array and wrap it in an ICollection property (if you need the internal array):

```
[DataContract]
public class BinaryResponse : ResponseBase
{
    // this is NOT a member of the DataContract
    private byte[] payload;

    [DataMember] public ICollection<byte> Payload {
        get { return this.payload; }
        set { this.payload = value.toArray(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this then FxCop throws the warning: CA2227 : Microsoft.Usage : Change 'Property' to be read-only by removing the property setter. Because collection properties should be read-only.